# Every time a string is turned to LPCWSTR or LPARAM it turns into chinese

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm doing a desktop app using winapi.

It only happens whenever I try to do it with variables, whenever I pass just text, everything works correctly.

I tried switching out SendMessageW for SendMessageA, but the strings are still displayed wrong. When the text is put in, it is displayed correctly only with SendMessageA and not SendMessageW.

```
case WM_COMMAND:
    switch (LOWORD(wParam))
    {
    case 2: 
        GetWindowTextA(TextBox, &text[0], len);
        wstring tst = L"test";
        
        SendMessage(TextField, EM_SETSEL, 0, -1);
        SendMessageA(TextField, EM_REPLACESEL, 0, (LPARAM)&tst);
        delete[] text;

        SetWindowText(TextBox, L"");

        break;
    }
```

[image]

And here I just put text instead and it works perfectly fine

```
SendMessageA(TextField, EM_REPLACESEL, 0, (LPARAM)"test");
```

[image]

Comment: Use `SendMessageW`

Comment: As I said in my post, it doesnt work either

Comment: `SendMessageW(TextField, EM_REPLACESEL, 0, (LPARAM)(tst.c_str()));` You are castring and `std::wstring` to `LPARAM` not the data it contains.

Comment: that works thank you, could you post it as an answer so I can close?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to Richard Critten

> `SendMessageW(TextField, EM_REPLACESEL, 0, (LPARAM)(tst.c_str()));` You are castring and std::wstring to LPARAM not the data it contains.

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code:

- you are clearly using an ANSI-based (`char`) window, not a Unicode-based (`wchar_t`) window, as evident by `SendMesaageA()` working when `SendMessageW()` doesn't. `std::wstring` is a Unicode string class. Use `std::string` instead.
- the Win32 API has no concept of C++ class types. `EM_REPLACESEL` is expecting an `LPARAM` whose value is a `char*` pointer to a null-terminated C-style string, but you are sending a pointer to a `std::wstring` object instead. Use the `std::string::c_str()` method to get a `char*` pointer to the string's null-terminated character data.

Try this:

```cpp
string tst = "test";
SendMessageA(TextField, EM_REPLACESEL, 0, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(tst.c_str()));
```